# React useCallback not updating state onChange on the first change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, usecallback

I'm trying to create a search dropdown list but my search filter is not being updated properly with `useCallback`. The searchFilter callback does not update values on the first `onChange`

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
const [opts, setOpts] = useState(allOptions);

const searchFilter = useCallback(
    (val) => {
        setInputValue(val);
        const filter = val.toUpperCase();
        const ops = options.filter((opt) => opt.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1);
        setOpts(ops);
    }, [inputValue] // state not being updated on first onChange
);

<textArea
    onChange={(e) => searchFilter(e.target.value)}
    value={inputValue}
/>

<ul>
    {opts.map((option) => (
        <li key={option.key}>
            {option.text}
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

I was able to fix this bug by taking out the callback:

```
const searchFilter = (val) => {
    setInputValue(val);
    const filter = val.toUpperCase();
    const ops = options.filter((opt) => opt.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1);
    setOpts(ops);
} // this works on every onChange
```

What is wrong with my implementation of `useCallback`?

I even tried adding a `ref` to the logic but that didn't work. I read in the React docs for many input changes they prefer using refs:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
const [opts, setOpts] = useState(allOptions);
const inputEl = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    inputEl.current = inputValue; // Write it to the ref
});

const searchFilter = useCallback(
    (val) => {
        setInputValue(val);
        const filter = val.toUpperCase();
        const ops = options.filter((opt) => opt.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1);
        setOpts(ops);
    }, [inputEl]
);

<textArea
    ref={inputEl}
    onChange={(e) => searchFilter(e.target.value)}
    value={inputValue}
/>
```

** note I tried adding a JS snippet but it seems I can't add react hooks to stackoverflow yet. Needs to handle React versions 16.8+. If there is a way I can do it please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work for me, what value is it that's not updating? The input value or the displayed options?

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mcnulty-pysjj

Comment: ah i added inputValue as a dependency not opts! and it seems to be working properly

Answer (score 0):

React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

For example, this code may fail to update the counter:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

Check this page about react: State and Lifecycle [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)